# Issues with PyQt5's OpenGL module and versioning (calls for incorrect _QOpenGLFunctions_(ver))

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt, pyopengl

I have been trying to get [the PyQt5 helloGL example code](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/opengl/hellogl.py) to compile.  When I try to build the solution, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\-PATH-\trunk\view\test.py", line 142, in initializeGL
    self.gl = self.context().versionFunctions()
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5._QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Compatibility'
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

In my PyQt5 folder, I've got:

```
_QOpenGLFunctions_4_1_Core.pyd
_QOpenGLFunctions_2_0.pyd
_QOpenGLFunctions_2_1.pyd
```

as my set of QOpenGLFunctions for different versions. I've tried to search all over how the call versionFunctions() works to see if I could just force it to use the 4_1_Core file, but to no avail. I've reinstalled PyQt5 twice now after a couple of restarts to see if it was weird registry shenanigans - this being after I made sure to have my graphics drivers updated so that the correct version of OpenGL was even on my system (if that was somehow causing an issue)

PyOpenGL is installed and updated and I've reinstalled it as well.

My eventual goal is to embed an OpenGL renderer into a Qt window, but I've not found a lot of examples on how to do that in python. I was using Vispy for a while but was running into tons of issues with that as well, as their old Qt examples don't work anymore either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the problem of using these 2 lines:

```
    self.gl = self.context().versionFunctions()
    self.gl.initializeOpenGLFunctions()
```

Instead, you should be creating a custom QSurfaceFormat with the proper major/minor version and using QContext's setFormat to make it work with a suitable opengl version.

In any case, I'd recommend you a much much simpler alternative. For all my pyqt opengl projects I just use [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/installation.html) directly on my widgets and I get the latest opengl version for free. Find below that hellogl example adapted to use PyOpengl directly, I've also added some routines to print your gpu information so you'll see the opengl version used will match your system's one (check it out with [gpu caps viewer](http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/) or similar):

```
import sys
import math

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QPoint, QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QOpenGLWidget, QSlider,
                             QWidget)

import OpenGL.GL as gl


class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.glWidget = GLWidget()

        self.xSlider = self.createSlider()
        self.ySlider = self.createSlider()
        self.zSlider = self.createSlider()

        self.xSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.glWidget.setXRotation)
        self.glWidget.xRotationChanged.connect(self.xSlider.setValue)
        self.ySlider.valueChanged.connect(self.glWidget.setYRotation)
        self.glWidget.yRotationChanged.connect(self.ySlider.setValue)
        self.zSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.glWidget.setZRotation)
        self.glWidget.zRotationChanged.connect(self.zSlider.setValue)

        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.glWidget)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.xSlider)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.ySlider)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.zSlider)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.xSlider.setValue(15 * 16)
        self.ySlider.setValue(345 * 16)
        self.zSlider.setValue(0 * 16)

        self.setWindowTitle("Hello GL")

    def createSlider(self):
        slider = QSlider(Qt.Vertical)

        slider.setRange(0, 360 * 16)
        slider.setSingleStep(16)
        slider.setPageStep(15 * 16)
        slider.setTickInterval(15 * 16)
        slider.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksRight)

        return slider


class GLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):
    xRotationChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    yRotationChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    zRotationChanged = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GLWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.object = 0
        self.xRot = 0
        self.yRot = 0
        self.zRot = 0

        self.lastPos = QPoint()

        self.trolltechGreen = QColor.fromCmykF(0.40, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        self.trolltechPurple = QColor.fromCmykF(0.39, 0.39, 0.0, 0.0)

    def getOpenglInfo(self):
        info = """
            Vendor: {0}
            Renderer: {1}
            OpenGL Version: {2}
            Shader Version: {3}
        """.format(
            gl.glGetString(gl.GL_VENDOR),
            gl.glGetString(gl.GL_RENDERER),
            gl.glGetString(gl.GL_VERSION),
            gl.glGetString(gl.GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)
        )

        return info

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return QSize(50, 50)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(400, 400)

    def setXRotation(self, angle):
        angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
        if angle != self.xRot:
            self.xRot = angle
            self.xRotationChanged.emit(angle)
            self.update()

    def setYRotation(self, angle):
        angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
        if angle != self.yRot:
            self.yRot = angle
            self.yRotationChanged.emit(angle)
            self.update()

    def setZRotation(self, angle):
        angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
        if angle != self.zRot:
            self.zRot = angle
            self.zRotationChanged.emit(angle)
            self.update()

    def initializeGL(self):
        print(self.getOpenglInfo())

        self.setClearColor(self.trolltechPurple.darker())
        self.object = self.makeObject()
        gl.glShadeModel(gl.GL_FLAT)
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_CULL_FACE)

    def paintGL(self):
        gl.glClear(
            gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        gl.glLoadIdentity()
        gl.glTranslated(0.0, 0.0, -10.0)
        gl.glRotated(self.xRot / 16.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        gl.glRotated(self.yRot / 16.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        gl.glRotated(self.zRot / 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        gl.glCallList(self.object)

    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        side = min(width, height)
        if side < 0:
            return

        gl.glViewport((width - side) // 2, (height - side) // 2, side,
                           side)

        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION)
        gl.glLoadIdentity()
        gl.glOrtho(-0.5, +0.5, +0.5, -0.5, 4.0, 15.0)
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.lastPos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        dx = event.x() - self.lastPos.x()
        dy = event.y() - self.lastPos.y()

        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.setXRotation(self.xRot + 8 * dy)
            self.setYRotation(self.yRot + 8 * dx)
        elif event.buttons() & Qt.RightButton:
            self.setXRotation(self.xRot + 8 * dy)
            self.setZRotation(self.zRot + 8 * dx)

        self.lastPos = event.pos()

    def makeObject(self):
        genList = gl.glGenLists(1)
        gl.glNewList(genList, gl.GL_COMPILE)

        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_QUADS)

        x1 = +0.06
        y1 = -0.14
        x2 = +0.14
        y2 = -0.06
        x3 = +0.08
        y3 = +0.00
        x4 = +0.30
        y4 = +0.22

        self.quad(x1, y1, x2, y2, y2, x2, y1, x1)
        self.quad(x3, y3, x4, y4, y4, x4, y3, x3)

        self.extrude(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        self.extrude(x2, y2, y2, x2)
        self.extrude(y2, x2, y1, x1)
        self.extrude(y1, x1, x1, y1)
        self.extrude(x3, y3, x4, y4)
        self.extrude(x4, y4, y4, x4)
        self.extrude(y4, x4, y3, x3)

        NumSectors = 200

        for i in range(NumSectors):
            angle1 = (i * 2 * math.pi) / NumSectors
            x5 = 0.30 * math.sin(angle1)
            y5 = 0.30 * math.cos(angle1)
            x6 = 0.20 * math.sin(angle1)
            y6 = 0.20 * math.cos(angle1)

            angle2 = ((i + 1) * 2 * math.pi) / NumSectors
            x7 = 0.20 * math.sin(angle2)
            y7 = 0.20 * math.cos(angle2)
            x8 = 0.30 * math.sin(angle2)
            y8 = 0.30 * math.cos(angle2)

            self.quad(x5, y5, x6, y6, x7, y7, x8, y8)

            self.extrude(x6, y6, x7, y7)
            self.extrude(x8, y8, x5, y5)

        gl.glEnd()
        gl.glEndList()

        return genList

    def quad(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4):
        self.setColor(self.trolltechGreen)

        gl.glVertex3d(x1, y1, -0.05)
        gl.glVertex3d(x2, y2, -0.05)
        gl.glVertex3d(x3, y3, -0.05)
        gl.glVertex3d(x4, y4, -0.05)

        gl.glVertex3d(x4, y4, +0.05)
        gl.glVertex3d(x3, y3, +0.05)
        gl.glVertex3d(x2, y2, +0.05)
        gl.glVertex3d(x1, y1, +0.05)

    def extrude(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.setColor(self.trolltechGreen.darker(250 + int(100 * x1)))

        gl.glVertex3d(x1, y1, +0.05)
        gl.glVertex3d(x2, y2, +0.05)
        gl.glVertex3d(x2, y2, -0.05)
        gl.glVertex3d(x1, y1, -0.05)

    def normalizeAngle(self, angle):
        while angle < 0:
            angle += 360 * 16
        while angle > 360 * 16:
            angle -= 360 * 16
        return angle

    def setClearColor(self, c):
        gl.glClearColor(c.redF(), c.greenF(), c.blueF(), c.alphaF())

    def setColor(self, c):
        gl.glColor4f(c.redF(), c.greenF(), c.blueF(), c.alphaF())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Great, I have been moving away from Vispy due to lack of activity on github. Do you have any links to good resources to learn more about PyOpenGL? I'm trying to visualize machine toolpaths (g-code) and meshes (stls), and struggling to kludgineer something. Working in pyopengl feels like it'll end better.

Comment: @fuchstraumer Glad the answer helped you out, consider to mark it as valid, about g-code and stls, please consider open another post so I'll be able to elaborate further also on that topic which is quite interesting btw.

Comment: @fuchstraumer About PyOpengl, I'd start by installing the wheel from this [website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl) and reading a little bit the [official documentation](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation). Once you've created the gl context if you're familiar with opengl or webgl there is no mistery at all.

Comment: @BPL and OP I am a maintainer of vispy and found your answer while trying to finish up PyQt5 compatibility. If you have any insight it would be much appreciated: https://github.com/vispy/vispy/pull/1394
I was researching why our method for getting the GL version when using PyQt5 doesn't seem to work when I found this answer. Thanks.

Comment: @BPL thanks for providing the PyOpenGL version of the Qt OpenGL example! Very helpful. One thing, maybe this is a rookie question, why are the x-, y- and zRotationChanged in GLWidget defined as class variables of the GLWidget class instead of instance variables?